# Event handler not firing on dynamic button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a dynamically created button with an onclick event handler. The problem is that when I click the button it does not hit the event in the code-behind.

```
protected void gvOrder_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    int index = 1;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlNewO") as DropDownList;
        txt = e.Row.FindControl("txtNewT") as TextBox;
    }
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        string listitem = Convert.ToString(index);
        ddl.Items.Add(listitem);
        index++;
    }
    ddl.SelectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        ddl.Enabled = false;
        txt.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowIndex != 0)
    {
        ddl.Items.Remove("1");
        //Create ED button


        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button btnED = new Button();
            btnED.ID = "btnED";
            btnED.CssClass = "buttonsmall";
            //btnED.CommandName = "ED";
            btnED.EnableViewState = true;
            btnED.Click += new EventHandler(btnED_Click);
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                btnED.Attributes.Add("ID", r.ItemArray[2].ToString());
            if (r.ItemArray[3].ToString() == "1")
            {
                btnED.Text = "Disable";
            }
            else 
            {
                btnED.Text = "Enable";
            }
            //Add button to grid
            e.Row.Cells[5].Controls.Add(btnED); 
            }   
        }


    }

}
protected void btnED_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Coding to click event
}
```

Comment: how many buttons are you creating?

Comment: Have you debugged into the code to see that it is hitting btnED.Click += new EventHandler(btnED_Click);

Comment: Can you post the gridview data binding code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem here is that when the page is being recreated on post back - there is no more button! Dynamic controls need to be added on the page on every post back to fire events properly. In your case however on the first load when the `GridView` is binding you add the button to the page. But on the post back after the click the button is not added again, because GridView is not data bound again. Therefore ASP.NET cannot derive the source of the event, and supresses it.

Fix here is to bind GridView with data on every post back. Literally if you had `if (!IsPostBack)` - remove it. Or you can add the button in the template field and play with visibility - may be an approach as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would much appreciate an up-vote if you feel my question was valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a click handler on Row Created not on Data Bound I believe.

```
protected void gvOrderRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Row.RowType) {
        case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
            Button btn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnED");
            btn.Command += btnED_Click;
            break;
    }
}
```